# Identity involving binomial coefficients, Stirling numbers of the second kind, and generalized hypergeometric series

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function, stirling-numbers

I have come across the following identity that involves binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$, Stirling numbers of the second kind $\left\{ m \atop j \right\}$ and generalized hypergeometric series $_p F_q(a_0, a_1, ..., a_p; b_0, b_1, ..., b_q; z)$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k^a \binom{n}{k}
&= n\ _a F_{a-1}(2, 2, ..., 2, 1 - n;1, 1, ..., 1; -1)\\
&=2^{n-m}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{n}{j}2^{m-j} \left\{ m \atop j \right\} j!\\
\end{align}$$

How on earth does this work? The link between the first two parts of the identity is conjectured in [one of my previous questions here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772324/general-formula-for-sum-k-0n-ka-binomnk-is-somehow-hypergeometric) and the link between the first and third parts of the identity are detailed in [the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923115/sums-sum-k-0n-kt-n-choose-k-where-t-is-a-positive-integer). But if I was given the second and third parts of the identity, I wouldn't know how to describe it, let alone prove it.

Any advice or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Where is $m$ in the first two expressions? Or is the third expression independent of $m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start with the hypergeometric

$$n \,  _a F_{a-1} (2,2,\ldots,2,1-n;1,1,\ldots;-1)$$

and obtain

$$n \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}
\frac{(m+1)!^{a-1}}{m!^{a-1}} {1-n+m-1\choose m} m!
\\ = n \sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m
(m+1)^{a-1} {m-n\choose m}
\\ = n \sum_{m=0}^n
(m+1)^{a-1} {n-1\choose m}
\\ = n \sum_{m=1}^{n+1} m^{a-1} {n-1\choose m-1}
= \sum_{m=0}^n m^a {n\choose m}.$$

For the second equality we can start from

$$2^n \sum_{j=0}^a {n\choose j} 2^{-j} {a\brace j} j!$$

getting with the usual EGF

$$2^n \sum_{j=0}^a {n\choose j} 2^{-j} 
a! [z^a] (\exp(z)-1)^j
\\ = 2^n a! [z^a] \sum_{j\ge 0} {n\choose j} 2^{-j} 
(\exp(z)-1)^j.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor in
$[z^a]$ and the fact that $(\exp(z)-1)^j = z^j+\cdots$. Continuing,

$$2^n a! [z^a] (1+(\exp(z)-1)/2)^n
= a! [z^a] (\exp(z)+1)^n
\\ = a! [z^a] \sum_{m=0}^n {n\choose m} \exp(mz)
= \sum_{m=0}^n {n\choose m} m^a.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Instructive solution as so often. :-) (+1) I just noticed that you also showed the first part. Nevertheless, I will leave the answer as the approach could also be useful.

Comment: The more the merrier.

Comment: This *[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770113)* with a clever solution in the cross-posted MO-post might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

In the following we use the rising factorials notation $(q)_{k}:=q(q+1)\cdots(q+k-1)$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}k^a}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\underbrace{\binom{n}{k+1}(k+1)^a}_{=:t_k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}t_k=t_0\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{t_{j+1}}{t_j}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}
> \left(\binom{n}{j+2}(j+2)^a\binom{n}{j+1}^{-1}(j+1)^{-a}\right)\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}
> \frac{(-1)\left(j+2\right)^a\left(j+1-n\right)}{\left(j+1\right)^a}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\frac{(2)_k^{a-1}(1-n)_k}{(1)_k^{a-1}}\,\frac{1}{k!}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n{_aF_{a-1}}\left(2,2,\ldots,2,1-n;1,1,\ldots,1;-1\right)}\\
> \end{align*}
> showing OPs conjecture is valid.

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774167/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for the hint. I've added an answer.